# Data of ListView keeps changing on scroll

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

Data of my listview keeps changing on scrolling listview up and down. Seems something is wrong with adapter. Below is code that I have used for Adapter.
I have two buttons in a listview item, accept and reject request.If request is either accepted or rejected then only one button will appear.if request is pending i.e P, both buttons will be displayed

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView_, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder view ;

    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView_);

    if (convertView_ == null) {

        convertView_ = inflator.inflate(R.layout.received_list_row, null);
        view = new ViewHolder();
        view.imageViewPage = (ImageView) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.received_postImage);
        view.postImageBg = (ImageView) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.received_postImageBg);

        view.txt_post_title = (CTextView) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.received_txt_post_title);

        view.txt_post_Date = (CTextView) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.received_txt_post_Date);
        view.txt_post_Time = (CTextView) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.received_txt_post_Time);

        view.llparent = (LinearLayout) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.received_llparent);
        view.llaccrej_btns = (LinearLayout) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.ll_accrejbtns);
        view.txt_acceptreq = (CTextView) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.textview_acceptreq);
        view.invisible_txtbtn = (CTextView) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.invisible_btn);
        view.txt_rejectreq = (CTextView) convertView_
                .findViewById(R.id.textview_rejectreq);

        convertView_.setTag(view);


    } else {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView_.getTag();
    }

view.txt_post_title.setText(list.get(position).getActivity_name());
view.txt_post_Date.setText(list.get(position).getActivity_postdate());


   view.txt_post_Date.setText(list.get(position).getActivity_postdate());
        view.txt_post_Time.setText(list
                .get(position)
                .getActivity_posttime()
                .substring(
                        0,
                        list.get(position).getActivity_posttime()
                                .lastIndexOf(":")));



  if(request_status.equals("P"))
              {

              }

              else if (request_status.equals("A") && view.txt_acceptreq.getTag().equals(position)) 
            {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;


            view.txt_rejectreq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.txt_rejectreq.setClickable(false);


            view.invisible_txtbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.txt_acceptreq.setText("ACCEPTED");
            view.txt_acceptreq.setClickable(false);



            view.txt_acceptreq.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.txt_acceptreq.setLayoutParams(params);

            }

          else if (request_status.equals("R") && view.txt_rejectreq.getTag().equals(position)) {

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;

            view.txt_acceptreq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.txt_acceptreq.setClickable(false);

            view.invisible_txtbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.txt_rejectreq.setText("REJECTED");
            view.txt_rejectreq.setClickable(false);

            view.txt_rejectreq.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.txt_rejectreq.setLayoutParams(params);


        }




        view.txt_acceptreq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("CLICKED ACCEPTED" + position);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                params.weight = 1.0f;
                view.txt_acceptreq.setText("ACCEPTED");
                view.txt_acceptreq.setClickable(false);
                view.txt_acceptreq.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                view.txt_acceptreq.setLayoutParams(params);
                view.txt_rejectreq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.txt_rejectreq.setClickable(false);
                view.invisible_txtbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                int user_id = list.get(position).getUser_id();
                int activity_id = list.get(position).getActivity_id();
                String status = "A";
                macc_rejRequestTask = new AcceptRejectActivityRequestTask(
                        maccept_rejRequestResponder, activity);
                AsyncUtil.execute(macc_rejRequestTask, "" + user_id, ""
                        + activity_id, status);

            }
        });

        view.txt_rejectreq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("CLICKED REJECTED " + position);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params   =                              new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                params.weight = 1.0f;

                view.txt_rejectreq.setText("REJECTED");
                view.txt_rejectreq.setClickable(false);
                view.txt_rejectreq.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                view.txt_rejectreq.setLayoutParams(params);

                view.txt_acceptreq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.txt_acceptreq.setClickable(false);
                view.invisible_txtbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                int user_id = list.get(position).getUser_id();
                int activity_id = list.get(position).getActivity_id();
                String status = "R";
                macc_rejRequestTask = new AcceptRejectActivityRequestTask(
                        maccept_rejRequestResponder, activity);
                AsyncUtil.execute(macc_rejRequestTask, "" + user_id, ""
                        + activity_id, status);

            }
        });


    return convertView_;
}
```

Comment: its normal, keep value live to be use as in Array List etc.

Comment: from your above code every thing is looking fine can you please confirm which data are repeated? provide some more info about it

Comment: show your full adapter class

Comment: added full code with explanation